# use objective-c in a swift framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I want to execute an objective-c code in swift cocoa touch framework
I want to execute an objective-c code in swift cocoa touch framework so in my .h file :

my mm.h file :

```
@interface mm : NSObject
- ( NSString * ) hiFounction;
@end
```

and in my .m file :

```
#import "mm.h"

@implementation mm

- ( NSString * ) hiFounction
{
            NSString *statez =@"hi !!";
    return statez;
}

@end
```

any pist of how I can use  my "hiFounction" in my swift cocoa touch framework? (I can't use a bridge here )

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem! got the same issue and finally solved it by re-wrapping the objective c codes in another framework. Well, I got it worked by creating another framework project, put all the objective C codes in the newly created framework, including it in my workspace, linking the build result and using the class from the newly created framework in my existing framework which is swift based. hope this can help.